# Underscore.js Get key from value in array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a simple way to get key from value?

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,10];
if(_.contains(arr, 3))
  alert(KEY of 3 (2))
```

Comment: You can use [array].indexOf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Opens [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/)
2. Looks on left
3. Finds [`_.indexOf`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf):

> `_.indexOf(array, value, [isSorted])`
>
> Returns the index at which **value** can be found in the **array**, or *-1* if **value** is not present in the **array**.

Comment: Oh sorry! Of coz it is. Thnx!